# Hanging Organizer in Bathroom

Tags: home, personal-care, bathroom, organization

I'm trying to design a shelf of sorts I can make that would hang on a bathroom door to accommodate a few bottles, combs etc. and a rod for hanging a towel to dry. Basically everything I need after a workout, condensed into a small space for keeping in a shared bathroom.

I'd rather not buy anything or spend a lot of time but that's a possibility. I have on hand some pipes, wood, a few baskets, fabric,  screws and other basic supplies - also wood working tools.

Does anyone know a simple design?

Comment: If you don't want to buy anything, you'll have to give us an inventory of items you already own in your home that we could use for this. For example, a reusable grocery bag could be hung over the door handle and hold most of your stuff.

Comment: @BrettFromLA Thank you for the suggestion, updated.

Comment: This seems more like it needs a search on Instructables.com.  Pretty sure they had a contest for this a couple years ago...

Comment: @Zeiss Ikon Not really. I guess if I was looking for inspiration to come up with the design myself.

Comment: @PerlCook Then you should not have posted it here as a question, anyway, there can be no suggestions in your creativity. And the better idea will be to meet some retailers, at least you could save some money.

Comment: @MANEESHMOHAN I meant at ZeissIkon that I could see where he was coming from but in fact I wasn't just looking for inspiration but rather a quick fix. That aside is this question off topic? If so apologies. I'm kind of new here but I know the standards are pretty strict.

Comment: Consider adding an actual question to your original post.

Comment: @James I understand you may have meant that sarcastically... However, thank you for the suggestion, updated.

Comment: I'm sorry if my suggestion sounded sarcastic.  I honestly didn't mean it that way.  You said in your post that "I'm trying to design...".  It wasn't obvious to me that you were asking for a quick fix, as you later stated in your comment.  I thought that you might get better answers if that was clarified in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your baskets likely need two or more points of connection, which can be the top corners but in some cases you can use a series of points in a vertical line in the middle. With some very sturdy baskets you can get away with just one point of connection, when using a rigid frame, but do check for droop and twisting of the basket itself.

Once you have decided how you can or have to connect the baskets to your frame you can start thinking up what your frame will look like.

I am a knots person and my initial reaction is to use rope, connecting the baskets on their ends to the ropes.
Which will then allow you to compress it while off the door but expand and give plenty of access when on the door.
To make this kind of hanger you either need two ropes with a hook to attach it at the top of each, or easier, one rope folded double with an eye in the middle. The way they handle the [rope in this rope ladder](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Rope-Ladder) shows what I try to say.

If you feel more like a rigid frame, by all means make one. 
You can make a single 'top down' frame, or you can make a few separate ones that you can hook into each other, adding more baskets when you need special items.
Or you can just use one basket which is big enough for your needs.

If you can attach a hook or nail to the door you can easily just use a loop or eye.
Otherwise you will have to add a hook that hooks over the top of the door. You can bend on from a flat piece of metal, as long as the metal is strong enough to hold the shape.
Or you can go for any of the 'over the top of the door' hooks you can find in shops.

Comment: Using rope, what a great idea. Project was a success.

Answer (score 1):

Even though a lot of designs are available, I am suggesting you one out of them. In this one, you could apply your creativity as which part of this, should be made up of steel, pipe or wood. I am not aware if a product of this image exist in your market or not, if do, I am not branding it and please do consider this for reference. You could substitute most of its parts with items you specified.

[image: Check this design]

Comment: (confused) That's not helpful at all.

Comment: @PerlCook: The image shows shelves that hang on a door.  It appears that a version of the product in the image could be constructed from pipes, wood, and baskets, all of which you claim to have.  If this answer is not helpful, you REALLY need to describe why not.

Comment: @James Amazing how we're all programmers here. I guess programmers like to live practically and LifeHacks helps them do that. Anyway, I think it's pretty obvious why the answer isn't much of an answer. But that's okay.